# How are these equivalent for normal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

If $A+\epsilon $ (where $\epsilon$ is a perturbation on the order of machine precision,) has an eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $A$ is a normal matrix, then the eigendecomposition of $A$ is $A=Q \Lambda Q^{*}$, where $Q$ is unitary.

Under those conditions, I have seen it written in my textbook that $\|(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\|=\|Q(\lambda I-\Lambda )^{-1} Q^{*}\|$. But I cannot figure out why these two things are equal.

Can someone show me why/how these are equivalent?

Thank you.

The $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the $2$-norm.

Comment: It's a fact that for both the spectral (2-) norm and the Frobenius norm, the norm is invariant under multiplication by an orthogonal matrix.  This is not true for most other matrix norms.

Comment: $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$, so $A-\lambda I$ is *not* injective, so why it is invertible?

Comment: Ah, really really good point GN Supporter.  I think I copied the statement from the textbook wrong....let me check.

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes I understand that the Q's do not affect the norm (2-norm, or Fro norm).  But then why are we able to stick the $\Lambda$ in there?

Comment: It would help to provide context if you cited the source that you got this from.

Answer (score 1):

This clearly isn't an exact equation, but rather a relationship that holds in the limit as $\| \epsilon \|$ goes to 0.

There's a notational confusion here, in that $\lambda$ in the statement of the problem is an eigenvalue of the perturbed matrix, and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of the original matrix.  I'll change the notation to use $\mu$ as an eigenvalue of the perturbed matrix $A+\epsilon$, and restate the proposition as

> Assume that $A$ and $A+\epsilon$ are normal matrices, $A$ has been diagonalized as $A=Q\Lambda Q^{*}$ and that 
>   $\| \epsilon \|$ is a small perturbation.  In the limit as $\| \epsilon
>  \|$ goes to 0, if $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A+\epsilon$, then to
>   first order,    $\|  (\mu I - A)^{-1} \|_{2} \approx  \| Q(\mu I -  \Lambda)^{-1} Q^{*} \|_{2}$

Since $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of the perturbed matrix, it is close to an eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$ of the original matrix $A$, with corresponding eigenvector $v_{i}$.  The perturbation theory for eigenvalues tells us that to first order,

$\mu \approx \lambda_{i} + v_{i}^{T}\epsilon v_{i}$

Thus the smallest eigenvalue of $\mu I - A$ is to first order,

$\mu_{smallest}(\mu I - A) \approx v_{i}^{T} \epsilon v_{i} $

Then to first order,

$\| (\mu I - A)^{-1} \|_{2} \approx \frac{1}{| v_{i}^{T} \epsilon v_{i} |} $

On the other side, the smallest eigenvalue of $\mu I - \Lambda$ is 
$\mu - \lambda_{i} \approx v_{i}^{T} \epsilon v_{i}$.  Thus to first 
order,

$\| (\mu I - \Lambda)^{-1} \|_{2} = \| Q(\mu I - \Lambda)^{-1} Q^{*} \|_{2} \approx \frac{1}{| v_{i}^{T} \epsilon v_{i} |}$

You can easily check this in MATLAB by creating random symmetric matrices $A$ and $\epsilon$ with $\| \epsilon \| \ll \| A \|$.

Note that this fails if for some reason $v_{i}^{T}\epsilon v_{i}=0$.  I believe that repeated eigenvalues in $A$ can also cause problems.